# Node js getting blank obj even after pushing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, async.js

Here I am trying to push data into my array, but it is always empty.

```
read_file: ['pass_fileData', function (result, cb) {
    let obj = [];
    async.each(result.pass_fileData, function (item) {
        knex
        .select('xxxxx')
        .from('xxxx')
        .innerJoin('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx')
        .where('xxxxx', '=', item)
        .then(function (data) {
            obj.push(data) // here I am pushing data to array
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            cb(err);
        })
    })
    cb(null, obj)
}]
```

In `CB(null, obj)` I am not getting any data but when I console I am getting data from db.

Comment: Quick guess, probably because `cb(null, obj)` is executed earlier , so before you pushed data to the array. Due to asynchronous operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your function is asynchrone. It means when your callback `cb(null, obj)` is called, the data is not there yet. You want to call the callback once every async functions are executed.

[`async.each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each) can take a third argumument which is a callback that will be called once the function is done.

Your code should look like this:

```js
read_file: ['pass_fileData', function (result, cb) {
    let obj = [];
    async.each(result.pass_fileData, function (item, callback) {
        knex
        .select('xxxxx')
        .from('xxxx')
        .innerJoin('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx')
        .where('xxxxx', '=', item)
        .then(function (data) {
            obj.push(data) // here I am pushing data to array
            callback() // Iteratee callback
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            callback(err); // Iteratee callback
        })
    }, function (err) { // end callback
      cb(err, obj) // Your callback that takes the obj
    })
}]
```

Comment: I am calling cb after async each block.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check the placement of the callback function as the third parameter of the `async.each` function.

Comment: Still it is getting called first.

Comment: I've edited tu put the full code. If you don't understand, check [`async.each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each) carefully

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an asynchronous call(`knex`) inside another asynchronous call(`async.each`), `cb(null, obj)` is not waiting for the previous async task to finish thus executing earlier. Also, if `async.each` is not a requirement you can get rid of it and just use the **Promises**. Just iterate over `result.pass_fileData`, store all the `knex` promises in an array, then use `Promise.all` with the array and that will do the job.

```
read_file: ['pass_fileData', function (result, cb) {
    const obj = [];
    const promises = [];

    // asuming "result.pass_fileData" is an array
    result.pass_fileData.forEach(function (item) {
        const singlePromise = knex
        .select('xxxxx')
        .from('xxxx')
        .innerJoin('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx')
        .where('xxxxx', '=', item)
        .then(function (data) {
            obj.push(data) // here I am pushing data to array
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            cb(err);
        });

        promises.push(singlePromise); // store all the promises in an array
    });

    Promises.all(promises).then(function() {
      cb(null, obj);
    });

}]
```

If you can use `async/await`(why not?) you can change the code a bit

```
read_file: ['pass_fileData', async function (result, cb) {
    const obj = [];
    const promises = [];

    // asuming "result.pass_fileData" is an array
    result.pass_fileData.forEach(function (item) {
        const singlePromise = knex
        .select('xxxxx')
        .from('xxxx')
        .innerJoin('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx')
        .where('xxxxx', '=', item)
        .then(function (data) {
            obj.push(data) // here I am pushing data to array
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            cb(err);
        });

        promises.push(singlePromise); // store all the promises in an array
    });

    await Promises.all(promises);

    cb(null, obj);
}]
```

Note the `async` keyword in front of `async function (result, cb)...` and `await` in front of `await Promises.all(promises);`

Hope it helps